# Ubuntu "live" Server 20.04 - How to create custom partition /boot + LVM on a single disk?

Tags: server, partitioning, lvm, 20.04

This is what I want to accomplish and I have to use the "legacy" image to do this but Canonical is phasing out the Debian installer in favor of their "live" installer so I need to get this figured out.  Here is what I am trying to create:

```
/boot - 1G, ext4

LVG volume group
- /root - 4G, ext4
- /var - 2G, ext4
- /home - 1G, ext4
- /tmp - 1G, ext4
- /bak - 1G, ext4
```

The problem is that I have a single 30 GB drive (Virtual Disk) and the storage configuration screen looks like this:

```
To continue you need to: Mount a filesystem at / and Select a boot disk
FILE SYSTEM SUMMARY
  No disks or partitions mounted.
AVAILABLE DEVICES
[ VBOX_HARDDISK_abc123, local disk, 30G ]
[ Create volume group (LVM) ]
USED DEVICES
  No used devices
```

If I select the "local disk" and choose "Use As Boot Device" then my option to create a volume group (LVM) or RAID goes away.

If I select "Create volume group," then the option is to use the entire disk which then removes the option to "select a boot disk" to continue. I can create a /boot inside the LVM but that is NOT where I want it to reside AND you cannot select it to actually boot from that anyway.

I could add a 1GB disk because it is a virtual machine but I am thinking about the process for a physical machine as well that only "presents" a single disk for the OS to use.

This is the guide with detailed steps I maintain for my base server rollout for 18.04 that I am trying to update for 20.04 - https://hammondslegacy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=244

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I assume that you tried to format and/or mount the 3rd (root) partition. You have to leave it unformatted and unmounted, this way the option for LVM remains.

**NOTE:** When you create the Logical Volumes inside of your Volume Group make sure to format and mount them, otherwise the installer will fail.

At the **Storage Configuration** step, move to **AVAILABLE DEVICES** and make the following changes:

1. Create EFI or BIOS partition; select **Use As Boot Device**.
2. Create boot partition; select **Add GPT Partition**, set the size,
   format as `ext4` and mount at `/boot`.
3. Create root partition; select **Add GPT Partition**, leave size
   empty (uses remaining disk space), do **NOT** format and do **NOT**
   mount (leave unformatted/leave unmounted).
4. Create Volume Group; select **Create volume group (LVM)**, name it
   and select partition `3` with the checkbox.
5. Create Logical Volume(s); Move to the newly created Volume Group,
   select **Create Logical Volume**, name it, set size (blank for
   remaining disk space), format it and mount it.
6. Repeat step 5 for all the Logical Volumes you want to create.

Hope this helps.

Comment: upvoted, works.

Comment: you're a savior!! thanks!!!